# Multiple prices on a ROR model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, e-commerce

I've struggled with this for the past few hours, I'm trying add the capability to a model where they are able to enter more than one price options to a model.
For example

Regular(price) 
    Luxury (price) etc..

I currently have a model

Pass.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
 validates_numericality_of :price,
   greater_than: 49,
   message: "must be at least 50 cents"

validates :title
```

My form for this model is normal letting a user enter a price. In order to have more than one price option how would I design that in the database or is this done more within the controller. Lastly if you make it available for user choice does it save as the official price for that model or would it be something extra to include when referencing the model's price within another controller. Example I'm using stripe to handle payment so if I have

```
 sale = Sale.new do |s|
   s.amount = pass.price
```

Would that represent the price the user selected. Sorry if this explained badly I haven't been able to find any resources to help me get started at solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

> In order to have more than one price option how would I design that in the database

```
class PriceOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pass
  ...
end

class Pass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :price_options
  ...
end

create_table "price_options", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "pass_id"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks @MilesStanfield this seems like it would work, How would I represent that in form views for example a simple add price button or something similar to add the different price options ?

Comment: depends on your implementation and exactly what you're trying to do in the form. Put the form from your view in your question and also any related controller code